# Ms-Word - Custom Contents - Numbering

Tags: microsoft-word

Using Ms-Word 2013, I have the following problem in my Table of contents:

My "automatic" table of contents gives the following output:

[image]

But I want the output rather like this:

[image]

PS: In the rest of my document, every numbering is correct. I do not want to change it manually because I want it to be a permanent solution (after updating the Contents).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the Appendices and References sections, go to `Insert` > `Page Number` > `Page Number Format`.  Change the "Number format" from `1, 2, 3...` to `i, ii, iii...` and then the table of contents will follow the number format.

Please make sure that main chapters and the appendices sections are separated by a "Section Break" but not a page break to make it work.